# Adding a tab app to teams with developer portal

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-static-web-app

I have created a Blazor WASM Static Web App which based upon a video from a year or so back by Microsoft I can then add to Teams using App Studio.

Well that has been replaced by Developer Studio, but apart from the need for an Application ID for the Static Web App it seems much the same...other than I get the following error...
[image]

Which I know isn't very helpful, but that's the very problem, how do I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Could you please ensure that the Application ID you're using for your Static Web App is correct? The error message you're seeing often appears when there's an issue with the Application ID.
Also please ensure that you have the necessary permissions to submit apps to Teams. You might need to have admin permissions or be part of a specific role to do this.